# VS remote building: "Makefile.Targets error: Cannot copy file remotely to directory"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ssh, makefile, remote-debugging

I'm working on a Makefile project on Visual Studio, modifying code from my laptop and remotely building on a Linux server which i connect to via ssh.

I configured my project Property pages as such:

**General**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WdP6.png

**Debugging**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI5ua.png

**Remote Build > Build command line**: cd $(RemoteProjectDir) && echo *password* |sudo -S make

In the remote project directory i have already every file of the project, Makefile too. When pressing *Compile* i expect VS to copy the changed code from the local directory, file by file, to the remote one, but the only error i get is this:

```
      Linux.Makefile.Target(108,5): error : Cannot copy \foo\bar\file.cpp remotely to /home/user/projects/MyProject/file.cpp
```

At line 108 of the file with target extension there is this tag:

```
 <CopySources
  Sources ="@(FinalSourcesToCopyRemotely)"
  AdditionalSources="@(AdditionalSourcesToCopyRemotely)"
  ProjectDir="$(ProjectDir)"
  RemoteProjectDir="$(RemoteProjectDir)"
  RemoteTarget="$(ResolvedRemoteTarget)"
  IntermediateDir="$(IntDir)"
  RemoteProjectDirFile="$(RemoteProjectDirFile)"
  UpToDateFile="$(CopySourcesUpToDateFile)"
  LocalRemoteCopySources="$(LocalRemoteCopySources)">
  <Output TaskParameter="ResolvedRemoteProjectDir" PropertyName="_ResolvedRemoteProjectDir" />
  </CopySources>
```

**Can this file be the cause of the problem for some reason? Is it good to tinker with a .targets file?**
I've already remotely build another project before with same configurations and similar Makefile (adapted for paths and file names) and it worked just fine.

[EDIT]:i've added the command *echo password| sudo -S make* to interact with the password request prompted by *sudo*, this worked in the other project and i still get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: if you get this error, just create another project with the same exact property as the first one, that'll do.

The problem was probably due to the fact that I changed the property several times before using the right one, which could have created some configuration (-ish) file, unchanged after the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You [can't use `sudo` when debugging](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/39) . So I'd guess you can't use `sudo` when building either. The problem is `sudo` prompts for a password and VSLinux can't handle that. One option is to configure `sudo` so it doesn't request a password but that's not advised. Can you change your setup so it doesn't require `sudo`?

Comment: I've found a solution for this, but i forgot to add it to the description. Unfortunately that's not the problem here. Now i've edited the question thank you for the reminder